# Discussion Board link with List Item - File not found

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, discussion-board

I have created a List A and a Discussion Board B. In order to link discussion in B with the item in A, I created a lookup column which get the value ID from item in A. This works pretty well when I create a new discussion in B, I can click on the lookup column to view the item in List A.

However, the problem is when I reply to the discussion, an error appears. It says that "File not found".

I believe that this is because the lookup column does not know which value to set. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have recently found the solution for this!!!

It looks like a bug in SPO. If I don't use "#" in the subject then everything looks good. However, if I put the # in, the error will appear!